# What was Suguru's relationship with his counselor?

Tags: the-knight-in-the-area

After Suguru died, his heart was implanted into Kakeru. Suguru's former counselor seems to play a psychiatric therapist role for Kakeru and says certain things to shake him up. Why does she do this? What kind of relationship did she have with Suguru to make her play mind games on his younger brother?

Answer (score 1):

Mine Ayaka was Suguru's former counselor as you said in your question. When he was alive he approached her for counseling on how to deal with pressure, because he had to live with all expectations for being the best Japanese player in his age and the future of Japan's soccer.

So they begging to be very close in this time, because almost nobody, even his brother, knew that Suguru had this kind of feeling, behind his apparent cool-headedness. As a professional, Mine Ayaka could listen to him, and he felt that could talk to her.

Then, Suguru's death surprised everyone, including her. And Suguru's heart was implanted in Kakeru. In this time, Mine Ayaka was the one who made the theory that Suguru's soul and memory were still living inside Kakeru's heart.

Answering your question, Ayaka is a psychotherapist, but she is addicted to spirituality and human mind. She also became very close to Kakeru, as she was to Suguru. According to Area no Kishi wiki:

> Despite her position as a clinical psychotherapist, she is fascinated
>   by spirituality and the human mind as shown by her strong interest
>   towards the theory of Suguru's soul still living in the heart that was
>   transplanted into Kakeru.

So, she became very interested in their case, trying to convince him to keep playing soccer, fulfilling his brother's dream, as she can study better this theory of memory transfer.

Comment: Some of the things she says appears to be counter productive, making Kakeru feel insecure about himself. She basically leads Kakeru to question himself: Who is really playing soccer, me or my brother? Trying to convince him to play soccer is one thing, but this is psychological warfare here. What's her motive for confusing Kakeru rather than aiding him?